# How load a yaml file inside an ansible custom module

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-module

I have an `ansible` custom module, that have a configuration file in `YAML` format.
Now the question is how should I load that `YAML` file inside the module?

**NOTE** as I understand I can't simply use something like `PyYAML` since `ansible` will run my module on the node that it is configuring and maybe that system does not have `PyYAML` installed.

**NOTE** Also `ansible` itself have `ansible.parsing.utils.yaml.from_yaml` it is not usable by the modules.

So funny as it may sound, I don't know how to load a `YAML` file in custom `ansible` module. Please help

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a great question. It does sound funny and you'd expect a simple answer but as far as i can see these are the facts.

The latest development branch of ansible has `/lib/ansible/module_utils/common/yaml.py` which can be used by modules because it is under `module_utils`. see [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/common/yaml.py)

If you look at the source code all it's doing is `import yaml as _yaml`, which you could do yourself inside your custom module. My understanding is this is using PyYAML, which is documented [here](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation). (someone correct me if I"m wrong! I don't fully understand the comment in that file stating "preferring the YAML compiled C extensions...")

Anyway, if your target machine does not have PyYAML you can always add a task to ensure its there. e.g.

```yaml
- name: Install PyYAML python package
  pip:
    name: pyyaml
```

and then use it in your own module with:

```py
from yaml import load, dump
try:
    from yaml import CLoader as Loader, CDumper as Dumper
except ImportError:
    from yaml import Loader, Dumper

# ...

data = load(stream, Loader=Loader)

# ...

output = dump(data, Dumper=Dumper)
```